# Exposing scripts to Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple existing Django app that does a few REST calls to a third party tool to create some users. Now, I have been tasked to expose the existing Django application to REST API calls from another platform. My question is, how do I pass parameters, sent in via REST requests from the third party tool, to my existing application, so that those parameters can be used to drive the REST requests executed in my app to create/update users in another third party platform. I assume this is possible.

This is part of the views.py file: (I want to expose this views page as a REST API a user can call and pass the nessary info (`server_name`, `user_name`, `password`, `site_url`) to it so that it can be passed to the addUser function to drive the subsequent REST request

```
def signIn(server_name, user_name, password, site_url, contentUrl):
    site_url = contentUrl[site_url]

    payload = {
        "credentials": {
            "name": user_name,
            "password": password,
            "site": {
                "contentUrl": site_url
            }
        }
    }

    headers = {
        "accept" : "application/json",
        "content-type" : "application/json"
    }

    signIn_req_url = "https://{server}/api/{api}/auth/signin".format(server=server_name, api=api)
    signIn_req = requests.post(signIn_req_url, json=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
    response = json.loads(signIn_req.content)
    headers["X-tableau-auth"] = response["credentials"]["token"]
    site_id = response["credentials"]["site"]["id"]
    return(headers, site_id)

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return(render(request, "index.html"))

def checkTest(request):
    cluster = request.GET.get("cluster")

    contentURLs = { "Default" : "" }

    site_url = "Default"

    server_name = server_dict[cluster]
    headers, site_id = signIn(server_name, user_name, password, site_url, contentURLs)

    sites_req_url = "https://{server}/api/{api}/sites".format(server=server_name, api=api)
    sites_req = requests.get(sites_req_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    sites_res = json.loads(sites_req.content)
    data = {}
    for item in sites_res["sites"]["site"]:
        data[item["name"]] = item["name"]
        contentURLs[item["name"]] = item["contentUrl"]

    signout_req_url = "http://{server}/api/{api}/auth/signout".format(server=server_name, api=api)
    signout_req = requests.post(signout_req_url, data=b'', headers=headers, verify=False)

    request.session["content"] = contentURLs
    return JsonResponse(data)

def addUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            server_name = server_dict[form.cleaned_data["cluster"]]
            add_payload = {
                "user": {
                    "name" : form.cleaned_data["user_id"],
                    "siteRole" : form.cleaned_data["privelege"],
                    "authSetting" : "ServerDefault"
                }
            }

            site_url = form.cleaned_data["site"]
            headers, site_id = signIn(server_name, user_name, password, site_url, request.session["content"])

            add_req_url = "https://{server}/api/{api}/sites/{site}/users".format(server=server_name, api=api, site=site_id)
            add_req = requests.post(add_req_url, json=add_payload, headers=headers, verify=False)

            signout_req_url = "http://{server}/api/{api}/auth/signout".format(server=server_name, api=api)
            signout_req = requests.post(signout_req_url, data=b'', headers=headers, verify=False)

            if add_req.status_code == 201:
                messages.success(request, 'User added successfully!')
            else:
                messages.success(request, 'Something went wrong while adding user!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect("index")
    else:
        form = addUserForm()
    return(render(request, "addUser.html", { "form" : form }))
```

The following is part of the app's url.py file

```
urlpatterns = [

    # CONTROL
    path("checkTest", views.checkTest, name="checkTest"),

    # PAGES
    path("index", views.index, name="index"),
    path("logon", views.logon, name="logon"),
    path("addUser", views.addUser, name="addUser"),
    ...
]
```

And the forms.py file contains the classes

```
class addUserForm(forms.Form):
    cluster = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={ "id" : "id_cluster" }), choices=TABLEAU_ENVIRONMENTS)
    privelege = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={ "id" : "id_privelege" }), choices=ROLES)
    user_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ "id" : "id_user_id" }), label="User ID", max_length=10)
    site = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={ "id" : "id_site" }))
```

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this?